# Trying to Calculate Basic Lunar Probabilities

Tags: probability

I'm trying to do what I thought was a basic problem but doesn't seem to be working out properly.  I'm looking at disproving a claim that tides cause earthquakes, where the main mechanism that people claim is that it happens during a new or full moon, and especially during a perigee moon (when it's closest to Earth).

People like to give ±1 week windows which is basically half a lunar cycle, so it seems basic that the probability an earthquake would happen, given random chance, would be 50% that it would happen within a week of, e.g., a full moon.  Similarly, since perigee/apogee happens roughly on the same timescale, it seems as though it would be 50% chance that an earthquake would happen within 1 week of a perigee moon.  Put the two together and you have a 25% chance that an earthquake would happen within both a perigee and full moon, correct?

(Important note, *updated*:  Actual period between new/full moons averages 29.52 days, actual time between perigee moons averages 27.56 days.  **However**, apogee and perigee are NOT normally distributed.  Apogee happens a mode of 27.78 days (mean is 27.55±0.27), while perigee is much more asymmmetric, having a mode of 28.4 days at the peak of approximately a Lorentzian.  Half the max of the Lorentzian is ±0.08 days.  But, the mean is 27.56 with a standard deviation of 1.12; the range is 24.6-28.6 days.  I'm thinking this could throw off the modeling?)

Assuming that's correct, I seem to be running into issues when trying to figure out the probability that an earthquake would happen by chance within ±X days of BOTH a perigee and full moon.  I thought the equation would be simply (2*X/(# days in lunar month, 29.5))*(2*X/(# days between perigee, 27.5)).

However, when I do a monte carlo simulation with 500,000 randomly chosen dates within the time period of 1933 to 2012 (just happens to be when I have earthquake data), the fractions do not line up.  For example, the simulation shows that 14.4% should be within 5 days of both a full and perigee moon, but my above math says it's only 12.3%.

I have checked the results of my simulation against days from perigee, apogee, new moon, and full moon times.  As expected from a random distribution with a large $N$, the number of times that the simulated earthquake is a given time period away from maximum perigee/apogee/new/full moon is even.  Except for perigee, where I see a fall-off for $>|±12.5|$ days from when it's closest to perigee.  I'm thinking this has to do with the non-Gaussian distribution of perigee times?  And could that account for the 2% difference at the 5-day example?

Is the best way to approach this, because these perigee times are a bit crazy, to simply go with the Monte Carlo results?

P.S. This has been updated to better reflect a correction I made in my data.  When I initially posted this, I had some incorrect full/new moon dates in my table that were throwing some results off.

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you estimating the proportion of days that are at different phases of the moon? You have actual data - that is, you know, for each day, where the moon was in its cycle.

Comment: I do, and the reason I did 43k points in the simulation is that's how much earthquake data I have.  So I can calculate the real fraction that happened within X days of both a full and perigee moon, but I want to compare that with basic statistical chance to show whether it's statistically significant.

Comment: It seems reasonable to estimate that proportion to determine the properties of the null hypothesis.

Comment: @StuartRobbins  How did you get 50% by chance in the first place.  Wouldn't chance occurrence be based on the expected time between earthquakes?  Also are you looking at a specific location or anywhere on earth?

Comment: Given what you've got, I would not simulate data at all. I would look into time series analysis. This would let you account for the fact that earthquakes in a given time period are not independent of earthquakes in the previous time period. It would also make it possible to look at moonphase (probably a variation on seasonality).

Comment: To Doug Zare's point you want the null hypothesis to be that the probability of an earthquake within a week of full moon is what normally happens by chance (not 50% though, probably much less).  Then the alternative would be that the probability is higher than the chance probability.  The chance probability should be something you can calculate based on your historical data on earthquakes.

Comment: When I do the calculation described in the question (by sampling daily for $80$ years) I get $12.3$% for the answer. In `R`: `days <- 1:(80*365.25);
k <- length(days[days %% 27.56 < 2*5 & days %% 29.52 < 2*5]);
k/length(days)`. Varying the starting phases changes the result by less than $0.03$%. The $15.2$% must be a computational error.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I've updated my question - I had an error in my tables for new/full moon times where some were crossed, resulting in non-uniform results when I corrected the Monte Carlo to large, random $N$ times.  I'm thinking this may be a case where I do have to simulate rather than can directly calculate the probabilities due to non-uniform spacing between perigee moons.

Comment: Spring tides occur *twice* a lunar cycle, so $\pm$1 week is actually ~95% of the time.

Comment: Also, @StuartRobbins: have you looked into [earth tides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_tide) at all? They seem relevant. Note that the [USGS site referenced there](http://hvo.wr.usgs.gov/volcanowatch/archive/1998/98_05_28.html) says "Scientists have found no correlation between the tides and earthquakes. Correlations between the tides and eruptions, however, have been identified", so you may be repeating work that's already been done...

Comment: @naught101 - ±1 week from a new or full moon would be nearly 100% of the time, yes, I'm actually combining the results for new+perigee and full+perigee and trying to determine if that's >chance (just listed one above since the variable names and lists would just be flipped for the other).

Comment: And yes, I know that there isn't a correlation, but I'm actually doing this for a podcast I run, "Exposing PseudoAstronomy," and this is the next episode topic.  So I wanted to do the analysis myself and then compare that with what the handful of pseudoscientists claim.  I find going through the exercise oneself is often enlightening, and I'll be in a better position to inform my listeners.

Comment: @StuartRobbins: yes, but your question states that you're trying to disprove the claim that **tides** cause earthquakes, not full moons. The tide cycle frequency is twice that of the moon phase frequency. Admirable goals, though :)

Comment: D'oh!  Yes, good point, must do new/full moon ±12 hours or something like that, I guess.  Though, the fact that I can bin at any interval I want (e.g., ±0.5 days, ±1 days, ±1.52346 days, etc.) can eliminate that issue.  These folks don't claim time resolution to be that precise, and often do, as I mentioned in the original query, claim windows of about 1 week as opposed to just a few hours.

Comment: If your code doesn't produce the same answer as whuber, then you probably have a bug in your code, and there isn't much we can do.

Comment: On a physical level it seems plausible that the gravitational pull on the earth of the moon, which produces a deflection in the earth's crust  might have some effect on releasing the stored energy of the plates at a tectonic boundary. A small injection of energy that pushes a stiction point over the threshold for movement. Is there a particular reason you feel that there might be no connection ?

Comment: @DouglasZare - I just did some tests, creating perigee and new/full moons at EXACTLY the rate I gave with no variability.  I can reproduce whuber's results -- the results that you'd get theoretically.  I then use the exact same code with the real times for the perigee and new/full moons and get the different results.  So I guess it really is the variability.  Is there any way to factor that in to get a better theoretical estimate, or do I need to do the Monte Carlo approach (which I can do ...).

Comment: @image_doctor - There are two reasons why I don't think there's an effect.  First, if it's that obvious, it should have been found by now.  Second, the proponents of it follow all the tactics of classical pseudoscientists -- that doesn't mean that they're wrong, but it's a strong indicator that their evidence is lacking when they resort to arguments from persecution rather than the data.  Also, the stats I've heard them claim are baloney (one guy said 1/3 of all >6 mag quakes in CA from 1933-1994 were all within a day of a new/full moon, and that's easy enough just to look up, and he's wrong).

Comment: @image_doctor - But, that's why I'm trying to do this experiment, to look at the data myself and figure out if it's above chance.  I've looked at the basics of if it's during a new/full moon or during perigee, and I know how to calculate what it would be for those by chance.  It's this whole combining the two that's giving me a headache, figuring out what it would be if it were purely random in order to test the null hypothesis.

Comment: Stuart, Your simple arithmetic calculation assumes that over the long run the occurrences of full moon and perigee are independent. The edit indicates they are not; that is sufficient to explain the difference. A more accurate mathematical model of these cycles would lead to a better estimate, but Monte Carlo simulation will work fine, too. However, the entire approach may be too primitive to stand up to criticism: by focusing on a fixed, large window, you are eliminating (a huge amount of) information. You need to explore how earthquake frequencies vary with the phase of both cycles jointly.

Comment: @StuartRobbins Applause for your examination of the raw data,I'm not sure what the conclusions will be if the gravitational effect is large enough to overcome stiction in in a few times out of a hundred and so doesn't significantly correlate with the instances of earthquakes in general.

Comment: whuber - I don't think I understand your "however" part.  Perhaps if I clarify - In the analysis, I'm looking at a wide range of windows relative to the time of perigee, apogee, new, OR full moon, AND looking at a variety of windows relative to the time of (perigee) && (new || full) moon.  The windows I'm using vary from±0.25 days to ±14 days (within which time ~100% should occur since the lunar cycle is roughly ±14 days from any given phase).  Does your "however" still apply?  If so, my lack of understanding remains.

Answer (score 4):

There is an oddity that $29.52/27.56$ is unusually close to $15/14.$ So, even though the proportion of times within $5$ days of both will eventually be about $\frac{2X}{29.52} \frac {2X}{27.56}$, it might take longer to converge than you expect. Instead of trying to calculate by a formula, you can simply ask a computer to count how many minutes are within $X$ of the perigee and full moon over that whole range. However, I don't think this effect is large enough to explain the difference between $15.2\%$ and $12.3\%$.

A Monte Carlo simulation normally would mean that you choose times randomly, not evenly spaced. One possibility is that you chose a gap which is too close to a simple rational times one of the periods. $79$ years/$43000$ is $1.49$ days, which might be too close to $29.52/20 = 1.48$. If you used exactly $29.52/20$ then instead of $10/29.52 = 33.88\%$ samples within $5$ days you would get $7/20 = 35\%.$ Again, this doesn't seem to be large enough to explain the discrepancy, but why add significant errors of this type?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I've updated my question - I had an error in my tables for new/full moon times where some were crossed, resulting in non-uniform results when I corrected the Monte Carlo to large, random $N$ times.